# SlidesJS for JavaScript Disabled User

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidesjs

I am pretty new to JavaScript.

I am using SlidesJS, which works perfectly fine.

However, when dealing with JavaScript disabled users, it is kind of tricky. For JavaScript disabled users, the images will be lined up. And I don't know how to deal with it because the images are embedded in the HTML code.

```
<div id="slides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
  ......
</script>
```

Is there a way to use SlidesJS still, but for JavaScript disabled user, the webpage shows one default image, and hides all the other images?

Comment: That sounds like the exact thing I am looking for, I will learn how to use it. Thanks!! @Blazemonger

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/), which can add a class to the HTML element if and only if JavaScript is enabled.

```
#slides > img + img {
    display: none; // may need to make this !important
}
.js #slides > img + img {
    display: block;
}
```

(Note that `modernizr.js` should be run before any other JS on the page.)

If all you want is JavaScript detection, you don't even need Modernizr -- just one line of code and the above CSS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = "js";
```

or, to be non-destructive about it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className
     = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className + " js";
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I think I need learn more about JavaScript, yea. @Blazemonger